# How to group by individual elements in arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have collections of shows with their genres attached, so that `Show.first.genres` returns `['horror','scifi',etc]`.

My goal is to calculate a users mean score by unique genres. The problem is that if I do a `Show.group(:genres)`, I get results by the whole sets of genres:

```
['horror','scifi']=>[list of entries]
['horror','gore']=>[list of entries]
```

I would rather get a count of all elements with horror in the genres, all elements with scifi, etc. Any ideas?

Here's some relevant schema information:

```
create_table "animes", force: :cascade do |t|
end

create_table "animes_genres", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "anime_id", null: false
 t.integer "genre_id", null: false
end

create_table "genres", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
end

create_table "library_entries", force: :cascade do |t|
end
```

These are all linked back and forth and I can generally access any relationships that exist via ActiveRecord.

Comment: How are the genres stored in the DB?

Comment: There's a `genres` table with just id/name, and then an auto generated `show_genres` table which links each show and its genres. The shows and genres share a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.  Can you please edit the question to include it, and any other information an answerer needs?  SO expects the question to stand on its own.

Comment: Updated with some schema info, let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Comment: Are you are just interested in the `count` of shows for each Genre, or access to the list itself? In a pinch you could run SQL like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48c02/1 directly.

Comment: I'd like the list itself. The entries contain the rating, which I'm trying to average across individual genres to see whether the user prefers action, drama, etc.

Comment: If you want to display everything by genre, wouldn't you start with Genre instead of Show? `Genre.each { |g| g.shows }` ...

Answer (score 1):

Or in a more Railsish way, you should probably start from `Genre` and do something like:

```
Genre.all.map{|g| [g, g.shows] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ActiveRecord Association goes both directions, then you should be able to look at the problem from the Genre Model's perspective.

```
Genre.find('space opera').shows
```

Comment: I'm not sure that going this way would be very efficient. Since at any time I'm only interested in the user's listed shows, going through the other way seems like starting with a huge funnel.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. So you are actually looking of an alternative to `myUser.shows.group(:genres)`?

Comment: More like a refinement. That works, but like I said I want it separated by single genre, not the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if that `Show.group(:genres)` returns a `Hash` of `[array of genres] => [array of entries]`, you can transform that into a `Hash` of `genre => [array of entries]`, by doing this:

```
by_genres = Show.group(:genres)
by_genre = {}
by_genre.default = []
by_genres.each{|ks,vs| ks.each{|k| by_genre[k] += vs }}
```

Or if you only want the count:

```
by_genres = Show.group(:genres)
count_genre = {}
count_genre.default = 0
by_genres.each{|ks,vs| ks.each{|k| count_genre[k] += vs.size }}
```